# What are the dangers of using an object as an AKKA actor?

Tags: scala, akka

In the code below I'm using an AKKA actor MonitorActor even though it's an object. I never see this pattern in production code although it seems to work well.

Does the below code have concurrency issues as a result of using an object as as Actor?

Are there any AKKA actor related 'gotchas' on show here?

```
case class SomeEvent(member: String)

class Example(eventBus: EventBus)(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem) {

  val members: AtomicReference[Set[String]] = new AtomicReference(Set())

  actorSystem.actorOf(Props(MonitorActor))

  private object MonitorActor extends Actor {

    eventBus.subscribe(classOf[SomeEvent])
    var isEnough = false

    override def receive: Receive = {
      case SomeEvent(member: String) =>
          val newMembers = members.updateAndGet(_ + member)
          if (newMembers.size >= 10) {
            isEnough = true
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the whole idea of message driven application is to be reactive, it's like I am sending mesaage of a certain type and actor is responsing on that, not the concurrency comes into the picture on the usage of the actor model and the pattern you are using to send the message to the actor, are they cpu or io bound operation if they are io then shoudl use futures else not and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One immediate question arising from this "pattern" is: what happens if the `Actor` is added to the `actorSystem` twice:

```
actorSystem.actorOf(Props(MonitorActor))
actorSystem.actorOf(Props(MonitorActor))
```

This is not a trivial question.  In large code bases there can be multiple files/packages where an Actor is materialized so the above scenario will likely come up if only by accident.

At best, each `SomeEvent` is processed twice by the exact same logic.  At worst you will get into nasty race conditions with `isEnough`.  So lets assume the best case.

Even in the best case scenario each SomeEvent will be processed by the exact same logic.  This isn't bad in the question's example because `members` is a `Set`.  But if it were a `List` you would start to get double insertions of the same event.

Another issue is having to protect ourselves from race conditions involving `members`.  A good reason for `members` to be an `AtomicReference` is to resolve the situation where the two "independent" Actors are trying to access `members` at the same time.  But this goes against the entire purpose of the Actor model.  From the [original 1973 formalism](https://eighty-twenty.org/files/Hewitt,%20Bishop,%20Steiger%20-%201973%20-%20A%20universal%20modular%20ACTOR%20formalism%20for%20artificial%20intelligence.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> The architecture is general with respect to control structure and does
>   not have or need goto, interrupt, or **semaphore primitives**.

A similar description can be found in the [akka documentation's introduction](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#introduction) (emphasis mine):

> The Actor Model provides a higher level of abstraction for writing
>   concurrent and distributed systems. **It alleviates the developer from
>   having to deal with explicit locking and thread management**, making it
>   easier to write correct concurrent and parallel systems.

So we have effectively broken the Actor model framework and all we got was not having to call a constructor.  Contrast the question's example code with the "preferable" implementation:

```
class MonitorActor() extends Actor { 

  val members: Set[String] = Set.empty[String]

  eventBus.subscribe(classOf[SomeEvent])
  var isEnough = false

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case SomeEvent(member: String) => {
      members add member
      isEnough = members.size >= 10
    }
  }
}
```

Now the developer doesn't have to worry about semaphores, race conditions, thread contention, ...  All of the logic and functionality within an Actor can be understood from a serial perspective.

Comment: Thanks! I think the first question (your first question) can be answered by making the object private which I should have done. I wonder if I can edit it now ... I'll try.

Comment: Re your second point, point taken and understood but I'm interested in subtle AKKA errors that might arise. Re how 'Props' works or maybe supervising strategy... it's hard to describe because I'm asking for issues I haven't thought of ... unknown unknowns!